# Apache rewrite existing rewritten url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know how to create rewrite rules in Apache but what I don't know is how to rewrite a previously rewritten url.

This is an old URL

`/boats-for-sale/fairline-squadron-55/1280`

and I need to redirect to

`/brokerage/boats-for-sale/boat/1280=-fairline-squadron-55`

How is this possible?  I assume I can create a rule that will do this form all rules that fall in this format

Comment: "rewrite a previously rewritten url" - in the same request? Are you using `.htaccess`? "I know how to create rewrite rules" - I'm wondering how this is different to any other rewrite/redirect? (Although, by the sounds of it, you need a redirect, not a rewrite.) What problem are you having specifically? Please include your current config and any attempts you have tried.

Comment: Why rewrite twice when you can do it right the first time? Modify your original rule.

Comment: I can't because it's Joomla that created the SEF urls in the first place and they're not stored in the .htaccess file.  I needed to add some redirects as the url has now changed and Google would have cached them.

Comment: This situation looks very specific to your site and wouldn't be applicable to anybody else.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't because it's Joomla that created the SEF urls in the first place and they're not stored in the .htaccess file. I needed to add some redirects as the url has now changed and Google would have cached them.

It sounds like you just need a regular *redirect*. The URL has changed, so you want to redirect from the old to the new for SEO. (It's unclear what you mean by "rewrite existing rewritten url" - as @closetnoc mentioned in comments, you would ideally "correct" the *first rewrite* in this case. But the SEF URLs in Joomla are not "rewrites" in this sense.)

Any redirect you implement in `.htaccess` will need to go *before* the Joomla *front-controller*.

It's not clear how "generic" you need this to be (how many URLs are we dealing with?), but to literally redirect the URL as stated, you could do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^boats-for-sale/fairline-squadron-55/1280 /brokerage/boats-for-sale/boat/1280=-fairline-squadron-55 [R,L]
```

(NB: That `=-` in the *substitution* does look a bit out of place?)

For a more generic solution, maybe something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(boats-for-sale)/([^/]+)/(\d+) /brokerage/$1/boat/$3=-$2 [R,L]
```

This will redirect the above URL and any URL of the form `/boats-for-sale/<anything>/<number>` to `/brokerage/boats-for-sale/boat/<number>=-<anything>`.

Change the `R` (temporary 302) to `R=301` (permanent) only when you have confirmed it's working OK - to avoid caching issues.